# How to convert String array containing nested array to JSON in c#

Tags: c#, json

How to convert sub-array to json. I have tried

```
 JArray _extra = JArray.Parse(extra.OrderOfferObject);
 if (_extra.Count() > 0)
    return Ok(new
    {
       Data = _extra, // ---
    }
```

So it did convert the string to JArray but skip the inner array. Here's the response:

```
Data: [{ Category: "Chicken Rice",
         Ingredients: "[{ExtraQuantity=1, ExtraPrice=11.99, ExtraTitle=Regular}, 
        {ExtraQuantity=1, ExtraPrice=0.0, ExtraTitle=Stuffed Cheese}, 
        {ExtraQuantity=1, ExtraPrice=0.0, ExtraTitle=Sauce BBQ}}]"}]
```

How do i convert the inner one, thanks.

**Update**

```
var extra = (from orderOffer in extraEntities.ORDER_OFFER
      where orderOffer.OrderOfferId == orderOfferId

      select new
      {
         orderOffer.OrderOfferObject
      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Where OrderOfferObject is an array of string type having nested array.I tried JArray.parse to convert to JsonArray. Alas! it did not convert the nested array, as you can see in response.

Comment: Sure, it would be nice if you would show how you believe your output should look like, is it just the string parsing, then why don't you parse the full extra object instead? How does your input look like? To me it seems your question was a bit rushed

Comment: Thanks. I'm already passing the full object. well in response you can see the value for Ingredients-key is a string not a JArray.

Comment: How can i convert the sub-string array to json, that's my question

Comment: What is your `sub-string` array?

Comment: what is the definition of `extra` and `OrderOfferObject`?

Comment: @RahulSharma i have array of array [string type]. i want to convert the nested array to json.

Comment: @BrianRogers i have update the post. checkout !

Comment: @Gigabyte Instead of JArray, have you tried using the JsonObject just like an array if you want to keep your json string.?

Comment: @RahulSharma i think not, JObject isn't my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your nested string is in a wrong format.

Currently your string object is this:

`{ExtraQuantity=1, ExtraPrice=11.99, ExtraTitle=Regular}`

It should be like this:

`{ExtraQuantity: 1, ExtraPrice: 11.99, ExtraTitle: Regular}`

Once your object is fine. JArray. Parse () only will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Let me check.